# Проблемы с удалением куки файла при первой загрузке страницы

Tags: php, cookie

Удаляю куки файл следующим действием:

```
setcookie("non_reg_user", " ", time() - 30, "/");
```

Далее ниже по коду у меня идёт if блок который проверяет удалён ли куки:

```
setcookie("non_reg_user", " ", time() - 30, "/");

if (!isset($_COOKIE['non_reg_user'])) {
echo "cookie is gone!";
}
```

проблема в том, что if блок срабатывает только после 2 перезагрузки страницы. Как можно сделать так что бы if блок срабатывал во время первой загрузки страницы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В вашем случае, без костылей - никак.

Надо понимать как работают куки, удаление куков - приходит в ответе сервера, но уже до этого от клиента пришли куки с вашим элементом. Все что вам остается - это ручками обнулять массив.

```
setcookie("non_reg_user", " ", time() - 30, "/");
unset($_COOKIE['non_reg_user']);
```

Это костыльно, но вот так вот. Можно найти либу нормальную, или самим разработать класс который будет такое делать, и красивее будет выглядеть.

Comment: спасибо большое  всё работает